# How to iterate a 2d list to print a table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a class like this:

```
class example:
    def get_a(self): return [1,2,3]
    def get_b(self): return [4,5,6]
    def get_c(self): return [7,8,9]
    def get_all(self): return [['a',self.get_a()],['b',self.get_b()],['c',self.get_c()]]
```

And now I would like to use the return value of `get_all` to print a table like this:

```
a b c
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I know I can get the same output via:

```
def example_print():
    x = example()
    print 'a b c'
    for a,b,c in zip(x.get_a(),x.get_b(),x.get_c()):
         print a,b,c
```

But I am clueless on how to iterate the 2d list returned by `get_all` to print the same, especially as I am looking for a way that does not have the number of items hardcoded (want to use same way of printing the list for different instances that may have more "columns").

Comment: Couldn't you just transpose the result of get_all and print it iteratively?

Comment: The list returned by get_all has three layers of nesting... Is that what you meant do do?

Comment: @RPGillespie that was my first idea, but then i dont know how to transpose without unnecesarrily copying stuff. complete pyhton noob here ;)

Comment: Here's a working example. https://repl.it/repls/HeavenlyJoyfulToolbox

Not sure if this is performant enough for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `get_all` definition to this:

```
def get_all(self): return ['a'] + self.get_a(), ['b'] + self.get_b(), ['c'] + self.get_c()
```

Then you'll be able to use something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

x = example()
for line in zip(*x.get_all()):
     print(*line)
```

Comment: how would I use formatting? In my real code the first column is strings that I would like to print with a fixed width? I know this is goes beyond the initial question, but maybe it is easy?

Comment: @user463035818 If you want to print all lines with some padding, you can do something like this: `print(*('{:<20}'.format(col) for col in line))`

Comment: thanks. I hope there will come the day when python doesnt just look like ascii art to me ;)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to use the `zip` transpose idiom, something like:

```
for x in zip(*e.get_all()):
    print(*x)
```

In Python 2, make sure you use:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Or better yet, just switch to Python 3.

If your list actually has two levels of nesting. Which would require your method to be something like:

```
return  [['a',*self.get_a()],['b',*self.get_b()],['c',*self.get_c()]]
```

Or something equivalent in Python 2...

Comment: oh wait no is it Python 2? D: In that case `print ' '.join(map(str, x))` I guess...

Comment: @jdehesa yes sure

Comment: yes, python2 sorry forget that. I wonder if the `python` tag is useful at all, given the huge differences

Comment: have to leave, will try it later, just in case you wonder why I am not accepting ;)

Comment: It is useful. People just assume Python 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried out this and it works.

```
class example:
    def get_a(self): return [1,2,3]
    def get_b(self): return [4,5,6]
    def get_c(self): return [7,8,9]


    def get_all(self):
        a = [['a', *self.get_a()], ['b', *self.get_b()], ['c', *self.get_c()]]
        r = []
        for line in zip(*a):
            r.append([*line])
        return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    E = example()
    v = E.get_all()
    for i in v:
        print(*i)
```